# How to get decision from recipeints clicking on alternatives hyperlinks in email bodytext?

Tags: forms, email, html-email

I'm not technical but trying.

I'm using `Tally.so` to gather information which is then emailed to another person via zapier and mailchimp.

I'd like to include hyperlinks/buttons in the email to the Another Person that say "Accept" or "Decline".

Whichever choice is made by the Another Person, I'd like that to open a URL - a tally.so form that carries the information from the first form, that went to the email, that went to the decision form.

I can handle the decision notifications from there.

I thought I'd be able to carry the data through using a custom URL with the ?fn=@firstname

Or through Zapier fields to put into Mailchimp/Mandrill and fire off single emails from there.

But I couldn't see how to get the infromation across to the third party, while also redirecting the email response/click back to a web form that could 'confirm' the response.

Comment: You could try something forward to a friend concept. You ask the user to send a link to the next person, they will fill the form out and then you can send an email?